# Connect to SQL Server DB with Active Directory Universal Authentication using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, authentication

First, I'm not a developer so I apologize if this is a redundant or unhelpful question.

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to connect to a certain server using Active Directory Universal Authentication, but I can't figure out a way to do this using Python.

When I login with the application, after I click connect, an Azure login screen pops up, and I am able to login with my username: myname@domain.com and password.

However, when I try to connect using pyodbc with the following code, I get the error below:

```
import pyodbc

def main():
    serverName = "name.database.windows.net"
    dbName = "DatabaseName"

    connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" + serverName + 
                 ";DATABASE=" + dbName + 
                 ";UID=myname@domain.com;PWD=mypassword")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    data = cursor.execute("select * from sometable;")
    allData = data.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    for i in allData:
        print(i)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server 'domain' requested by the
>   login. Client with IP address 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to access
>   the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal
>   or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a
>   firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to
>   five minutes for this change to take effect. (40615)
>   (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]

I know there have been posts about similar issues, but I am not sure this is the same problem. I have to use Active Directory Universal Authentication for this server. I have tried all of the SQL Server drivers that return from pyodbc.drivers() with no luck. I am using the same IP address to login through SQL Server Management Studio as when I am attempting it through the Python program. Is there a different module I can use to login with Azure, or is this impossible to do?

For reference, the popups that I see when I login through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio are below. I have been stuck on this for a while, so any help is much appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error message if I have **not** set Azure SQL firewall:
[image]

We can via azure portal to set **SQL server firewall**, like this:
[image]

After I add the firewall settings, I can use your python script to query, python script works for me.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why I need to use a different IP address to login using Python than the one that I use to login in SQL Server Management Studio. Is this a configuration issue? I do not currently have the administrator permissions to change the firewall settings.

Comment: Does your python And ssms run on the same machine?

Comment: I am running them both from the same computer -- is it possible that SSMS switches over to run the login process on a virtual machine when I use this authentication method or could something weird with multifactor authentication be happening (sometimes I have to enter my password twice in two different popups in SSMS)?

Comment: @user5932842 yes, could you please change another authentication?

Comment: @user5932842 Have you try it? does that work for you?

Comment: @user5932842 Have you solve this issue? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: I don't have permission to change the firewall settings unfortunately. Thank you for the help though.